# How to show checkbox (checked or unchecked) in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport 5.2.0. I'm trying show a parameter as checkbox: checked or unchechecked. How I can solve this task?

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Kudo

I'm using two images to display checkbox or uncheckbox. In each image, using Image Expression else if. ex: `$P{param}.equals("TRUE") ? $P{imagecheck} : $P{imageuncheck}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a text field with this expression:

```
$F{b}!=null?"þ":"¨"
```

and set font: **Wingdings**.

The first symbol is a checked box, the second is an unchecked box.
So, if I want a check I just send a character from database in field b. If I want a blank box I leave b field null.

... and check this too:
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/
it provides information like "How to ship the required fonts with your report templates when deploying them in the target application, using font extensions."

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. External links are dangerous, because they could become invalid at any time, and then your answer would lose value. So please [edit] it and add at least a summary of what can be found there. Also, you might want to explain how your expression works, and format it as code (just select it and press Ctrl-K). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put images to create a checkbox. Just put a 11x11 rectangle. and add 2 pieces of 9x9 lines like "\" and "/" and laminate them(put on top of each other). Make the line at bottom Opaque and right click and send it backward. Make the line at top "not opaque". If not showing one of them true, just play with these back or front settings. Then center those laminated lines into your rectangle. After all you can set print when expression parts by code. thats all!

By the way you can reverse "\" line to "/", by line properties > direction > "bottom up" or "top down" settings. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use unicode ensure your jasper report has an encoding of:
    ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

...

<field name="COLUMN_1" class ="java.lang.Boolean" />

...

<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
    <![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_1} ? "\u2713":"\u2717"]]>
</textFieldExpression> 

...
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]